# iOS tab bar not show modal view

Tags: iphone, ios, modalviewcontroller

I want to show modal view in the start of the app but it doesn't appear. This is my code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self initDataBase];
    CustomerModel *customer = [[[CustomerPersistor alloc] init] getLoggedCustomer];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UIViewController *profileViewController = [[[ProfileViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProfileViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    profileViewController.title = @"Profile";
    UINavigationController *profileNavigation = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:profileViewController] autorelease];

    self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:profileNavigation,  nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    if(customer == nil) { NSLog(@"HO");
        ViewController *login = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    //login.delegate = self.tabBarController.view;

        [self.viewController presentModalViewController:[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil]  animated:YES];
    }
    return YES;

}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: My guess is because you've set the tab bar to the root view controller, so self.viewController has no actions. Try self.tabbarController (this might not work tho as tabbarController is an array of viewController) presentModal...etc. However I'd strongly recommend against doing this here, the delegate should not be used in this way. The modal should be loaded on viewDidLoad in your first viewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there doesn't appear to be a self.viewController property that is set, and you're instantiating the same "ViewController" twice.  This is all wrong:

```
ViewController *login = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil]; 
//login.delegate = self.tabBarController.view;
[self.viewController presentModalViewController:[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil]  animated:YES];
```

Try moving this code to your viewDidLoad of your profileViewController...i.e. let the TabBarController load along with its first tab's view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Initiate an instanse from the model view like this:

```
modelView = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Please follow the list below:

1. Set the viewController model presented style

   ```
   [modelView setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPageSheet];
   ```
2. Then present it using:

   ```
   [self.viewController presentModalViewController:floorView animated:YES];
   ```
3. Then, set the size and location of the model controller like this:

   ```
   modelView.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 700, 550);//it's important to do this after presentModalViewController
   modelView.view.superview.center = self.view.superview.center;//self.view assumes the base view is doing the launching, if not you might need self.view.superview.center etc.
   ```

Hope this help you.